# Music play/pause button with one image - unsure why my JS/CSS code isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am working on a project, and I am trying to create a music button in the navigation bar. When you click on it, a song plays and clicking on it once more pauses it.
I have tried several versions, but unsure why they aren't working. Had a look on codePen for ideas, but still no luck. Hoping someone is able to help.
I managed it to work at one point, but it didn't pause at all, so I re-wrote the code.

This is the relevant HTML code:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item nohover">
    <audio id="music-button">
      <source src="Zara%20Larsson%20Lush%20Life%20Lyrics.mp3" preload="auto" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
    <div id="music-button-container">
      <div id="play-pause" class="play"></div>
    </div>
    <!--<a onclick="musicPlay()"><img src="music2.png" width="65px"></a>-->
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the CSS code:

```css
#music-button-container,
#play-pause {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 50px;
}

.play {
  background-image: url(./music2.png);
}

.pause {
  background-image: url(./equalizer.png) !important;
}
```

Finally, the JavaScript code, where I think the issue lies.

```js
var music = document.getElementById('music-button');
     var controlButton = document.getElementById('play-pause');

     function musicPlay() {
        if (music.paused) {
        music.play();
        controlButton.className = "pause";
         } else {
           music.pause();
           controlButton.className = "play";
         }
       }
     
     controlButton.addEventListener("click", musicPlay);
     music.addEventListener("ended", function () {
     controlButton.className = "play";
     });

     /* This is what I have tried as well*/

     document.querySelector(".play-pause").addEventListener("click",
     function() {
     if (music.paused) {
        music.play();
      } else {
        music.pause();
      }
     });

     function musicPlay() {
       var music = document.getElementsById("music-button");
       return music.paused ? music.play() : music.pause();
      }

     var isPlaying = false;

     function musicPlay() {
      return music.paused ? music.play() : music.pause();
     }
       music.onplaying = function() {
       isPlaying = true;
     };
     music.onpause = function () {
       isPlaying = false;
     }
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".play-pause").addEventListener("click",` - this line currently throws an error, because there is no element matching that selector in your HTML.

Comment: Thank you! I tried putting the JS code within <script> just before closing body tag and that done the trick. I'm just unsure why that made such a difference?

Comment: See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680/1427878)

Answer (score 0):

Bro If you only use one condition in the if statement then it wont work
Imagine this, the audio isn't even started yet but this doesn't mean that it is paused

```js
// Use this code
const play = document.querySelector(".play-pause")

// Using arrow function here, dont get confused
play.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  if(music.paused || music.currentTime >=0){
    music.play()
  }
  else{
    music.pause()
  }
})
```

This will definetely work
For more help with your music website

Visit mine
https://audioelemente.pages.dev